# How to apply this easing transition on scroll? WITHOUT jQuery

Tags: javascript

l found this `script` (that l don't understand) :

```
function scrollTo(c,e,d){d||(d=easeInOutQuart);var a=document.documentElement;if(0===a.scrollTop){var b=a.scrollTop;++a.scrollTop;a=b+1===a.scrollTop--?a:document.body}b=a.scrollTop;0>=e||("object"===typeof b&&(b=b.offsetTop),"object"===typeof c&&(c=c.offsetTop),function(a,b,c,f,d,e,h){function g(){0>f||1<f||0>=d?a.scrollTop=c:(a.scrollTop=b-(b-c)*h(f),f+=d*e,setTimeout(g,e))}g()}(a,b,c,0,1/e,20,d))};
function easeInOutQuart(t) {
    return t < .5 ? 8 * t * t * t * t : 1 - 8 * (--t) * t * t * t
}
```

But it works perfectly on my attempt to `scroll` to the top (so this isn't the problem) :

```
document.getElementById('toTop').onclick = function() {
    scrollTo(0, 2500, easeInOutQuart);
}
```

[**DEMO THERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/wreefakt/3/)

Well, can someone help me please to rectify THIS `script` below which doesn't work in pure `vanilla JS` :

```
var  elements = document.querySelectorAll('.nav li a'),
     target;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     var element = elements[i];
     element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          target = this.getAttribute('href');
          console.log(target);
          scrollTo(target, 2500, easeInOutQuart);
     });
}
```

[**ATTEMPT LINK NAV**](https://jsfiddle.net/wreefakt/4/)

`target` is correct so l don't know why it doesn't work...

Thank you!

Comment: What seems to be the problem ?

Comment: Where'd you find the script? It would be a whole lot easier to digest an unminified version of it. Also, can you update your question with any errors it is throwing?

Comment: Somewhere in stackoverflow...

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa scroll doesn't work on nav's scroll.